# Win32 ComboBox: Programmatically select (highlight) string from the list, without update the edit control

Tags: winapi, combobox, vb6

My goal is to Programmatically select items from the List of the combo box, but without updating the edit control. The same can be achieved with the mouse. E.g. when you drop down and hover an item from the list, that item is highlited. And that is all. If you want to select in it the combo box (e.g. move it to the edit control) - you must click on the LisBox.

I tried with CB_SELECTSTRING. But it automatically updates the ComboBox edit control with the selected text which is not what I want. I want to do this using raw Win32 or VB6

Thanks

Comment: This would be pretty confusing for the user.

Comment: Why? It is same as you are hovering with the mouse over the list box

Comment: Maybe I did't understand what you are __actually__ trying to achieve. Elaborate your question and describe the user experience you want.

Comment: The title is anything but self-explanatory. It talks about **selecting** an item, whereas you then go on to explain, that you want to **highlight** an item instead. This question sounds like it is part of some UI automation kludge. With that out of the way, what are you **really** trying to accomplish?

Comment: OK I realized that I used "select" incorrectly. I had to use "highlight". I apology for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big difference between *highlighting* an item in the drop-down list and actually *selecting* an item to make it active. `CB_SELECTSTRING` *selects* an item, as its name implies.  But there is no official ComboBox API to *highlight* an item, though.

However, you can display the drop-down list manually ([`CB_SHOWDROPDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775919.aspx)), and either:

1. move the mouse over the desired item so the list can perform hot-tracking logic.
2. manipulate the list directly.  Use [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775839.aspx) or [`GetComboBoxInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939.aspx) to get the list's `HWND`, and then send [`LB_SETCURSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761342.aspx) to it.

Comment: Thanks. #2 is exactly what I needed.